# htaccess: Redirect a Dynamic URL - Show only Static URL - Double Content

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite rule to get clean urls.. the only problem is, google shows some dynamic url and i dont want to serve dynamic urls.

What I want: if a user types in the dynamic url, he gets redirected to the clean url.. example:

```
    http://www.example.com/?index=bananas 
    (if someone types that in, he gets redirect to the url above)
    http://www.examplcom/bananas/
```

this is my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !apple\+banana
RewriteRule ^(.*)\+apple\+banana/$ ?q=$1 [L]
```

thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, retry :)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^index=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^/ /%1? [R=302,L]
```